# query to fetch table names from dba_table with (repeat 1.2.3...as prefix)

Tags: sql, oracle

Need query to fetch table names from dba_tables but wants to assign serial numbers (repeat 1.2.3...as prefix to table name like below.)

```
1:table_name1
2:table_name2
3:table_name3
1:table_name4
2:table_name5
3:table_name6
```

and so on.

Comment: `row_number()` comes to mind - but what condition causes it to restart from 1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to order by table name, you can use:

```
select case when mod(row_number() over ( order by table_name), 3) = 0
         then 3
       else
         mod(row_number() over ( order by table_name), 3)
       end case,
       table_name
from dba_tables
```